# How to turn off completion (enabled by default in Arch)?

Tags: autocompletion, installing, linux-arch

When I install vim from repository on Arch Linux, it has a completion feature that I don't like. What is it called and how do I turn it off? (It is active even with a blank .vimrc.) I would rather get vim exactly as it is in, e.g., Linux Mint.

[edit 2] here's an example of one of the things it does. (This is after I've enabled syntax highlighting and line numbers.)

[image]

[edit] the output of :scriptnames

```
/etc/vimrc
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim
~/.vimrc
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/UltiSnips.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/snippets.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/winter.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/default.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/DoxygenToolkit.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/UltiSnips.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/a.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/airline-themes.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/airline.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/init.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/parts.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/bufexplorer.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/ctrlp.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/filebrowser.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/fugitive.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/guicolorscheme.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/imaps.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/indent-object.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/jad.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/jedi.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/libList.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/minibufexpl.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/project.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/supertab.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/surround.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/tagbar.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/taglist.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/vcsbzr.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/vcscommand.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/vcscvs.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/vcsgit.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/vcshg.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/vcssvk.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/vcssvn.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/workspace.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/manpager.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/themes.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/plugin/UltiSnips_after.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/UltiSnips.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax/python.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/jedi.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/ctrlp.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/tagbar.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/branch.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/po.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/section.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/themes/dark.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/themes.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/util.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/builder.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/python/jedi.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/python/jedi.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/ctrlp/utils.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
```

Comment: The full output of `:scriptnames` would certainly help.

Comment: @romainl Thanks, I did not know about that command. I've edited it in.

Comment: It looks like you didn't just install Vim but have a long list of plugins installed as well (Arch Linux seems to package some)? At any rate, it's difficult to answer this question, as "completion feature" is rather vague. What completion? Where? When?

Comment: I guess the vague "completion feature" is the one provided by supertab (line 38 of the output)? I'm surprised: I thought Arch was well loved because it comes with a minimalist install, how comes so many plugins are packaged by default?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I think it would be that Arch packages all of these; I didn't install any additional plugins (at least not on purpose!?). That's why I'm having trouble with googling solutions. I provided a screenshot of it in action in python.

Comment: OK, the package manager has a "vim-plugins" meta-package that seems to have been installed alongside vim. (Maybe by me? I don't recall doing it.) Removing it removes the completion feature. (@statox, removing supertab on its own did not change things.) I'll try to find out which of those it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I unknowingly had installed on my system the set of packages "vim-plugins".

Among these was "vim-jedi" which seems to be the one causing behavior I didn't want.

I used the package manager to remove it.

Thanks very much for the commenters who helped me diagnose this!